# How to exit a program with an exit code: C#

Tags: c#, .net, exit, exit-code

How to exit a program with an exit code in C#?
In java it would be [`System.exit(int code);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Comment: Have a look [**here**](http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either:

- Declare your `Main` function as returning `int`, and return a value from it, or
- Call [`Environment.Exit(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Returning a value from `Main` is a little nicer than exiting the process in the middle of a method, but this is presumably the same advice that applies to Java, C or C++.

Comment: FYI, the docs for the possible return values for Main - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx