# Write a application to get or return an exit code

Tags: c#, .net

How to get an exit code from an application. Example: I call: System.Diagnostic.Start("regsvr32", "mydll.dll"); How to get an exit code from regsvr32?

And how to write an application which returns an exit code (like regsvr32). Thanks.

I'am using .NET 4.0 & C#.

Comment: The second part of your question (and title) is [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529393/how-to-exit-a-program-with-an-exit-code-c/3529402#3529402). Consider editing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually two separate questions, but... The exit code is the value returned from the program's Main function. So:

```
public static int Main()
{
    // code

    return 0;
}
```

Will return an exit code of 0. Unless the preceding `// code` does something different.

Use the Process' ExitCode property to get this value from the application to execute.

0 is typically returned when the program succeeds. Anything else is a failure but this is a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should be sufficient.

```
private int CallSomething()
{
    using ( var p = new Process() )
    {
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("RegSvr32");
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return p.ExitCode;
    }
}
```

[`p.ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) is the exit code of the called process.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helper class which shows you how to get the exit code, along with the output stream and error stream. Might be what you are looking for.

```
/// <summary>
///   Run an executable.
/// </summary>
/// <param name = "executablePath">Path to the executable.</param>
/// <param name = "arguments">The arguments to pass along.</param>
/// <param name = "workingDirectory">The directory to use as working directory when running the executable.</param>
/// <returns>A RunResults object which contains the output of the executable, plus runtime information.</returns>
public static RunResults RunExecutable( string executablePath, string arguments, string workingDirectory )
{
    RunResults runResults = new RunResults();

    if ( File.Exists( executablePath ) )
    {
        using ( Process proc = new Process() )
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.OutputDataReceived +=
                ( o, e ) => runResults.Output.Append( e.Data ).Append( Environment.NewLine );
            proc.ErrorDataReceived +=
                ( o, e ) => runResults.ErrorOutput.Append( e.Data ).Append( Environment.NewLine );

            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

            proc.WaitForExit();
            runResults.ExitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid executable path.", "executablePath" );
    }

    return runResults;
}

public class RunResults
{
    public int ExitCode;
    public StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();
    public StringBuilder ErrorOutput = new StringBuilder();
}
```

In order to return an exit code yourself, just return an integer from your main() method.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an integer from your Main() method within a console app, for example.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff
        return 0; //everything is good
    }
    catch //you will want more specific error-handling, catch-all is for example only
    {
        return 1; //something blew up!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Process.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) property

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `System.Diagnostic.Start` method returns a `System.Diagnostic.Process` class.  This class has an `ExitCode` Property which you should be able to use to get the return value.